# Internet Connection Sharing stops working every 50 days

Tags: windows-server-2016

I now have a solid pattern of this happening every 48-50 days whereby on a number of our Windows Server 2016 servers, the Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) stops working and I have to go into properties, then sharing and there disable it and re-enable it for it to start working again.

It happens sometime between 48-50 days like clockwork (haven't been able to narrow it more, but somewhere between 48 and 50 days, every 48-50 days without fail for the last year).

This is used to allow Internet connectivity on VM's and having to do this every x days is a real pain!

Any ideas on what is causing this and how to avoid it happening?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Is your system up to date?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yep

Comment: FWIW, an unsigned 32-bit millisecond counter will overflow in 49.71 days. [Plus ça change, plus c'est la même chose](https://www.cnet.com/news/windows-may-crash-after-49-7-days/)

Comment: Do some memory monitoring its likely some memory leak in something slowly filling up and 50 days later or so sillently halts. I've seen servers going down in a 5 to 6 months period a real slow build up leak, a real long time ago NT4 period.